# What is the Offcanvas folder for in Shopware 6 storefront

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In Shopware storefront within the view folder **home/vendor/Shopware/storefront/Resources/storefront/views/layout/navigation/Offcanvas**

I see an 'offcanvas' folder within the navigation folder but can not decipher what it is used for. Can you explain this folder to me? I am building a Shopware 6 theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An off-canvas menu is a sidebar that can be toggled to slide/fade in from the sides of the screen. For the navigation it is used in mobile viewports. For local development, browsers have ways to simulate how a page would look like on a mobile device: [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/), [Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/responsive_design_mode/)